# Windows App Certification Kit Binary Analyzer Failed Check

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Attempting to submit a Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app to the store. Solution has several projects, including a Models, Contracts and a Shared DLL. These 3 projects/dlls are failing the Windows App Certification Kit tests with:

`File XXX.Shared.dll has failed the NXCheck check`
`File XXX.Contracts.dll has failed the NXCheck check`
`File XXX.Models.dll has failed the NXCheck check`

Microsoft say the problem is a Security threat issue, because these dlls are running code that is stored in a data segment.

The suggested resolution from Microsoft is to add the /NXCOMPAT switch to the Linker options, however, I do not have a Linker page in the properties in any of the 3 offending projects. I've tried adding this to the compilation symbols, but no change.

These DLLs are low payload - they contain not much more than POCO data objects, interfaces and a few static methods. I've built a new default blank Windows Phone app and added these projects to the Solution. If I reference any one of these projects in the main phone app project, the certification fails with the same result.

So the problem is definitely isolated to these 3 projects. There are other projects of the same type included in the solution, but these do not exhibit the same problem.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what these DLLs could contain which causes this Binary Analyzer failure?

I've compared compiler / build options and checked the project properties etc, but can't see any obvious differences.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a post-compile Build Event referencing an obfuscation library in each of these projects. Solution was to remove it as the library was third party.